# Aerospike REST gateway, failed build with an exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, gradle, aerospike

im trying to install Aerospike REST Gateway, after running first command ./gradlew build (and waiting for 2 hours) its shows something like this :

```
2142 tests completed, 1660 failed

> Task :test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/andalabs/aerospike-rest-gateway/build/reports/tests/test/index.html

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2h 57m 33s
8 actionable tasks: 8 executed
```

Mostly those failed task is from package  "com.aerospike.restclient" which i dont have any clue what i have to do with this

What im missing here? im using Ubuntu 20

Comment: There were failing tests. >> that kind of explains it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `./gradlew build` runs the tests before it builds the jar file.  It looks like the integration tests are failing, and the unit tests are passing. This is likely because the server is not available on localhost.  Run `make build` instead to bypass the tests.